# Find the curve connecting $(x_1,y_1)$ to $(x_2,y_2)$ that minimizes the surface area of the volume of revoluion

Tags: calculus-of-variations

Given two points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$, find the curve $\gamma$ connecting them such that the surface area of the volume obtained when rotating the curve along the $x$-axis is minimized.

First assume that the curve is given by $(x,y(x))$. Then the surface described has area
$$ 2\pi \int_{x_1}^{x_2} y(x)\sqrt{1 + \dot{y}(x)^2}dx = 2\pi \int_{x_1}^{x_2} F(y,\dot{y})dx.$$
The Euler-Lagrange equations tell us that such a minimizing curve satisfies
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} - \frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial F}{\partial \dot{y}} = 0.$$ Now I can work out these derivates but the term $\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial F}{\partial \dot{y}}$ becomes a complete mess (in the sense that solving the DE that arises looks impossible). Is there another way to solve? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The resulting equation is a bit of a mess, but there is a 'standard' trick (multiply the resulting ODE by $\dot{y}(x)$ and simplify).

Comment: Minimizing $\int_a^b y(x)\sqrt{1+y'2(x)}\>dx$ under constraints leads to a catenary, hence we shall see a catenary surface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get down to

$$y'(x)^2-y(x)y''(x)+1=0,$$

and I'm sure that somebody on this site can solve that.

What you need to do once you have calculated the derivatives is to multiply by $(1+y'(x)^2)^{3/2}$ to simplify.

**EDIT:** Actually consider the quotient rule:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{u}{v}\right)=\frac{vu'-uv'}{v^2}$$

with the role of $v$ played by $y(x)$ and that of $u$ played by $y'(x)$

so that we have

$$y\cdot y''-y'\cdot y'=1=\frac{y^2}{y^2}\Rightarrow \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{y'}{y}\right)=\frac{1}{y^2}.$$

Therefore

$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\ln(y)=y^{-2}...$$

thought I'd be able to go somewhere with that... as I said somebody will have no problem at all from here.

Comment: Ok thanks, so I should soldier through the equations and solve

Comment: The solution usually boils down to a first order equation...

Comment: I solved the DE, check out my answer.

Comment: @Slugger Nice; well done.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to solve the DE

We can solve the DE
$$\dot{y}^2-y\ddot{y}+1=0$$
 using the substitution $u(x) = \dot{y}(x)$. Then the differential equation turns into
\begin{eqnarray*}\label{zoveel}
    -y\frac{du}{dy}u +u^2 + 1 = 0.
\end{eqnarray*}
This can be seen by realizing that
\begin{equation}
    \dot{u} = \frac{du}{dx} = \frac{du}{dr} \dot{r}.
\end{equation}
Rearranging yields
\begin{equation}
    \frac{dy}{y} = \frac{udu}{1 + u^2}.
\end{equation}
Integration yields
\begin{equation}
    \frac12 \ln |1 +u^2| = \ln |r| +C 
\end{equation}
So that
\begin{equation}
    1 + \dot{y}^2 = Cy^2.
\end{equation}
Now we obtain
\begin{equation}
    y' = \sqrt{Cy^2 - 1},
\end{equation}
so that
\begin{equation}
    \frac{dy}{\sqrt{Cy^2 - 1}} = \pm dx
\end{equation}
The solution to this equation is given by 
\begin{equation}
    y = \frac{1}{c_1} \cosh(c_1 x + c_2).
\end{equation}
Now we have two initial conditions, namely that $y(0) = y_0$ and $y(x_1) = y_1$. The first condition gives
\begin{equation}
    c_1 = \frac{\cosh(c_2)}{y_0}.   
\end{equation}
The second initial condition then says that
\begin{equation}
    y_1 = y_0 \frac{\cosh(c_1 x_1 + c_2)}{\cosh(c_2)}
\end{equation}